# How can I display extra information in a table?

Tags: website-design, data-visualisation

So I recently got this theme and I have been modifying it to fit my needs for the application and I came across a piece of design in which I am unsure about.

I have a table which contains bans, these bans have a lot of data attached to them for instance Player's GUID, Admin's Ingame Name, etc. along with the ban entries.

I wanted to know...where can I display this extra data. There's not enough data to display on another page along with the fact that the data should be easily accessible as well as fast to get to.

In the image below you can see that I had this idea: You click on a ban entry, it expands downwards exposing some extra data however I don't know to display this data so it fits with the rest of the theme.

Please halp!

[image: Sigil Design]

[Link to full image](https://i.imgur.com/lAl7BbK.png)

Comment: Perhaps a Light Box effect or making use of an addition right column since it seems you have some horizontal space to scale down?

Comment: I unfortunately cannot make use of the horizontal space as this has been taken at 1980 x 1080 resolution so it's pretty much hires. At lower resolutions the table is rather cramped :/

Comment: Is the "extra" data in your screenshot? I don't think I'm seeing it, and if it's not there I'm not sure how anyone could suggest how to lay it out. This question is a bit unclear if not brainstorming in general.

Comment: This is really more of a UX Design question in my mind. My vote is to send it that way for more extensive feedback. You'll want to craft your question in a broader way like "how to best present additional table data" so it's not too specific to your application.

Answer (score 2):

A Possible solution could be to add a Modal dialogue box from a link titled 'additional info'.

**What Is a Modal Box?**

Put simply, a modal box is a scripted effect that allows you to overlay a small element over a website. The primary benefit of modal boxes is that they avoid the need to use conventional window pop-ups or page reloads. In short, modal dialog windows are a means to swiftly show information to users on the same page they are working on, thus improving the usability of your site and decreasing unnecessary page reloads.

[source](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/modal-and-modeless-boxes-in-web-design--webdesign-2282) webdesign.tutsplus.com

You might want to add more details to what you are trying to achieve to get further and more accurate help.